# Real Analysis - Rational approximation of Pi

Tags: real-analysis

The claim is $\exists$  N such that for $\it{all}$ k > N, $\frac{2 + Cos(k)}{\sqrt{k+1}}$  > $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$. The inequality fails, for example, at k=22, k=355 and k=3126535, all of which are related to very good rational approximations of $\pi$ with (necessarily) odd denominators. It therefore boils down to whether the improvement in rational approximation to $\pi$ for larger k can effectively outpace the difference in reciprocal square-roots of k and k+1. Any ideas on an analytical approach welcome.

Comment: I believe you are claiming that the irrationality measure of $\pi$ is $2$, that is a long-standing open problem.

Comment: Thanks Jack - I've done some reading on the topic and suspect you may well be correct.